# Connection failure has been detected: HQ119014: Did not receive data from invm:0

Tags: hornetq, jboss-eap-6

actually I have a TimerWS running correctly, but in a few hours I have this error

```
WARN  [org.hornetq.core.client] (hornetq-failure-check-thread) HQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: HQ119014: Did not receive data from invm:0. It is likely the client has exited or crashed without closing its connection, or the network between the server and client has failed. You also might have configured connection-ttl and client-failure-check-period incorrectly. Please check user manual for more information. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT]

WARN  [org.hornetq.jms.server] (Thread-3 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-451033388)) Notified of connection failure in xa discovery, we will retry on the next recovery: HornetQException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=HQ119006: Channel disconnected]



Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
```

Any idea?

Comment: Seems an hornetQ bug : https://issues.jboss.org/browse/HORNETQ-1314

Answer (score 0):

Something is going wrong with a client's connection to the server.
These warnings are generated from the server which determines that a client is no longer responding.When that happens, the server cleans up the server-side resources related to the client's connections.

I have seen this many times by clients which are not properly coded to close their resources when they exit (finally block).
Have a look also for network problems which break the connection.